# How to efficiently sync Android database with web database

Tags: android, sqlite

My android app database syncs with a central database on my web server. My problem is efficiently syncing it.

The table is set up as "id" (primary key), "town".
The android app wants all the ids of the people in a given town

My current process is:

```
get list of all ids for town "A"
set all existing records in Android database to "old"
add/update ids in the list to "current"
delete any records still set as "old"
```

The bottle neck comes in the add/update process which is:

```
for each id {
    result = update WHERE _id = id
    if (result == 0) {
        add record
    }
}
```

Is there a statement like WHERE _id IN(id1, id2, id3, id4 ....) that would act as add/update if already there??
Or am I going about it completely wrong?

Thanks

Comment: No, the Android database is synced using the data from the web database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

then why you updating the data, at the time of synch cant you delete all the data in android device  and add the latest data from the server

i am saying this because it will flexible, **first delete all and insert all(latest ones)**

Comment: Insert is always taking more time than insert. If you are synchronizing too often this is not good.

Comment: WRT future proofing, when I add more data, like name, address etc, that will have to be re-downloaded as well.

Comment: ya, then it to update the data is more preferable, you can do onethg you can take an additional field(isSync as boolean) it will say you whether this data is been updated on your device or not?

Comment: Is that not what the "current" / "old" field is doing?

Comment: How about not deleting all records but moving them to a temporary database, then fill new one with current ids from server. Any blanks can be filled from the saved off database, or gotten from server if brand new?

Comment: ya it do, but i insist to use flag concept

Comment: but the flag bit is the bottleneck

Comment: Looks like I'm going to have to rebuild the database and address the issue of extra data when it comes up. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. build a table on server side (ID, Town, UpdateTime)
2. add triger on UPDATE/INSERT to modify UpdateTime
3. store LastUpdate time on device with fx SharedPreferences
4. send LastUpdate to server
5. build JSON or XML with ID, Town from a table WHERE UpdateTime > LastUpdate +(place in JSON or XML) (CurrentTime GETDATE()
   from DB)
6. do insert/updates in device db update, LastUpdate to CurrentTime

Comment: But if someone changes their town from "A" to "B", their details will be left on devices that sync with town "A", hence the "current" "old" approach

Comment: So it should be 2 way sync ... Well its more complicated... U shold try to find zmth like microsoft sync framework

Comment: two* way? The Android app does not change the data, but the data can be changed in the web database